# Configure WebAPI and MVC routes in One ASP.NET when the {controller} has the same name on both the API and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am setting up an MVC 5 site.  In the same project, I setup a WebAPI scaffolding.

For MVC, my routing looks like this:
**{controller}**/{action}/{id}
I want my API route to look like this:
**Person**/edit/15

For WebAPI, my routing looks like this:
api/**{controller}**/{id}
I want my API route to look like this:
api/**Person**/15

The problem is, I have a controller called PersonController.cs which inherits from **Controller**.  I seem to need another controller called PersonController.cs which inherits from **ApiController**.

Can this be done, or is there another solution?

Comment: Yes, put them in different namespaces and their controllerfactories will find them just fine, as they check for inheritance of (Api)Controller.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the answer I was looking for.